# IOS - How do you get current scrollview position in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

I have a scrollview in swift which user can scroll up and down freely. When a user scrolls, stops at somewhere and hit a button in the scroll view, how do I know the current position of the scrollview?

To be detailed, I need a

```
currentPosition: CGPoint
```

such that the scrollview will be exactly the same as it appears when I do

```
thisScrollView.setContentOffset(currentPosition, animated: false)
```

Comment: scrollview.contentOffset and scrollview.contentInset if used

Comment: @LloydKeijzer I tried scrollview.contentOffset, but it gives the position before user scrolls, not after user scrolls. contentInset is something different.

Comment: Implement the delegate UIScrollViewDelegate and set it to your scrollview now you can read the contentOffset inside of the scrollViewDidScroll method. This will be the contentOffset after scrolling. Heck you can even check it after decelerating. Don’t forget to store it in a global scoped variabel so you are able to scroll to it programmatically later.

Comment: @LloydKeijzer Thanks, that's very helpful. I have other functions that scrolls the scrollview, thus the contentOffset I got was already changed. Now I use global variable to record it and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the current position of scrollView.

```
scrollView.contentOffset
```

[**contentOffset**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/1619404-contentoffset)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the scrollView.contentOffset.y for your visible screen in all scrollable area(ContentSize).
And you can use the all scrollable are --> scrollView.contentSize.height

scrollView.contentSize.height = scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height